# Open Terminal and Run command as different User to show status messages

Tags: terminal, install, mobile-device-management

I am currently working on deploying software from our MDM to Mac's.  The software installs correctly but there is no user feedback during the install unless they know to manually go and find a specific log file and look in there.

What I would like to do is have a script open a Terminal window and the run the following command:

`less +F /path/to/logFile.log`

This way the user can see the status of progress.

Does anyone know a way that I could make this pop up automatically?

#### Edit

We are using Cisco Meraki for our MDM.  Meraki's Mac software capability are more limited then some other vendors so it would have to be run by a custom made script.

Basically what I would ideally like to achieve is similar to what Deploy Studio does when in their Net Boot set with the logs in the background:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which MDM software you are using. I am in a JAMF Pro shop and we use [SplashBuddy](https://github.com/ftiff/SplashBuddy) for displaying status as software installs.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using JAMF - I'll edit my question with MDM details, but that looks pretty nice.